# how to display records from database using vb.net

Tags: combobox

i have multiple combo box that are needed to display the names of candidates, from president to muse,without pressing any buttons, but i don't know how to do it..

Public Class Frm_ElemBallot

```
Private Sub ComboBox7_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ComboBox7.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Frm_ElemBallot_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
```

End Class

how i should connect it to database?

Comment: Please search [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=populate+combobox+vb.net&rlz=1C1AFAB_enUS452US452&oq=populate+combobox+vb&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l3.4232j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&rlz=1C1AFAB_enUS452US452&sclient=psy-ab&q=populate+combobox+vb.net+database&oq=populate+combobox+vb.net+da&gs_l=serp.1.0.0i22i30l4.5829.6496.0.7396.3.3.0.0.0.0.158.411.0j3.3.0....0.0..1c.1.20.psy-ab.mN6fPsjuvDs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49784469%2Cd.aWc%2Cpv.xjs.s.en_US.MpiVkF51mpA.O&fp=1fb426de7cf3e564&biw=1110&bih=759), there are ***many*** results

Answer (score 0):

you should try this way

**Sample Code:**

```
Try
            Dim cn As SqlConnection
            Dim strCnn As String = "Your data base connection string"
            cn = New SqlConnection(strCnn)
            cn.Open()
            Dim comm As New SqlCommand("Your sp or Command text to get the data from DB", cn)
            '' If ur using Sp then Commandtype= CommandType.StoredProcedure if  'is  Text then comm.CommandType=CommandType.Text
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(comm)
            Dim ds As New DataSet
            da.Fill(ds)
            ListBox1.Items.Clear()
            If ds.Tables.Count > 0 And ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                ListBox1.DataSource = ds
            End If
            ''Close your connections and commands.
        Catch ex As Exception
            ''Handle error if any
        End Try
```